# Requery a subform within a tab control

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have several controls on this form in addition to a tab control with 3 separate pages. I want the subform(s) within each page to requery when a value is selected on the page above.

So for the purposes of explaining this..

I have an event `On_Click()` on a field called `Address_ID`. It's meant to take tha value of that ID in addition to two other IDs, `Cust_ID` and `Location_ID`, and requery the subform `Order_Sub` within the `Orders` page.

I've named the tab control pretty blandly, just `tabCtl`.

So far I've tried every way imaginable to reference the subform, but to no avail.

```
Forms!Record_Details!Orders!Orders_Sub.Requery
```

That doesn't work, but I assume that it should. What gives?

Comment: Do you have the the record/row source of the subforms set in the properties dialog? If so, are you not resetting it with the new values?

Comment: The subforms each have a query record source that includes criteria to set three fields equal to three control values on the form. Those controls are set to the ID values when each of them are clicked. So I assumed that, since all controls were populated, a simple requery would suffice.

Comment: Have you tried using the AfterUpdate Event instead of click? I am assuming that the value of Address_ID changes, right?

Comment: It changes on_click, that's correct. I haven't tried it on other event types.

Comment: try this Forms.Record_Details.Form.Orders_Sub.Requery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steve

You do not need to reference the tab control in your code. Just reference and requery the subform itself

```
Forms.Record_Details.Form.Orders_Sub.Requery
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly now. Can you explain how that works or point me to an article that might describe it? Does the form just not treat the tab as a parent to the subform?

Comment: Well technically, its still a sub form of Record_Details. So trying to reference the tab control is not only not needed, but was most likely confusing the compiler. If you look at the tab control properties its doesnt state that subforms are available at that level https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/tabcontrol-object-access